# SpriteKit bodyWithTexture: sprite leaving the bounds of the scene

Tags: sprite-kit

I recently found the new way to give a sprite a physics body rather than just using a circle, but when i use this new method, the sprite will hit the border of the screen and push its way through and just leave.

I have the scene border setup:

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
```

and this is the method I'm trying:

```
zombie.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:zombie.texture size:zombie.size];
```

How is my sprite pushing its way out of the scene?

bit masks:

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

zombie.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
zombie.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = gearCategory;
zombie.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 1;
```

Comment: could you give a few more details?  are you using an action on your zombie?  how is it "pushing" its way through?

Comment: Please post the code where you have set the contact, collision and category bitMask values for the scene and zombie physicsBodies.

Comment: No action. Touching the screen changes a velocity variable used in the update:(NSInterval)currentTime method which changes the position of the sprite.If you touch the screen, the sprite will continue on that velocity until you tap somewhere else. When i say pushing, i mean when it travels into a wall,it will hit it, vibrate a little, then just travel through it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why youd be having this problem.  I dont know why youd need to use the update method either.  If you are setting a velocity then the sprite will maintain that velocity until something changes it..  I'll share my viewcontroller and scene.  I'm not having the same problem you are.  What is the difference between this and what you're doing?

have you tried doing this without `bodyWithTexture`?  I know its a fairly recent addition to spritekit.  Maybe the shape of your texture is odd and is causing the problem.  Try just doing it with `bodyWithRectangleOfSize`

**ViewController**

```
@implementation GameViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    GameScene *scene = [[GameScene alloc]initWithSize:skView.frame.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}


@end
```

**GameScene**

```
@implementation GameScene

SKSpriteNode *_test;

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
        _test = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(10, 10)];
        _test.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
        _test.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_test.size];

        [self addChild:_test];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint touchPos = [touch locationInNode:self];

        CGPoint newPosition = CGPointMake(touchPos.x - _test.position.x, touchPos.y - _test.position.y);
        CGFloat angle = atan2(newPosition.y, newPosition.x);
        CGPoint normalized = CGPointMake(cos(angle), sin(angle));

        _test.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(normalized.x * 200, normalized.y * 200);

    }
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

@end
```